# Implemet trie in Java in a memory efficient manner

Tags: data-structures, heap-memory, trie

I have to read a 10 GB file and find out the most frequent phrases in the file. 
I am reading the file in chunks using a scanner and storing the phrases in a
Trie data structure.
I will search the phrases later in order to update their count and hence have used the trie data structure for efficient search. I have implemented the Trie
using Hashmap in java as shown below.

```
class TrieNode {
        char data;
        Map<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
        boolean isLeafNode;
        int positionMinHeap = -1;
        int frequency;

        TrieNode() {

        }

        TrieNode(char data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }
```

But this solution takes up a lot of heap space. And if all the phrases are distinct in the file, the Trie would take a huge amount of space.Is there any other way that I can implement Trie in a memory efficient manner?

Comment: I would use a top-k [stream summary](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~raywong/comp5331/References/EfficientComputationOfFrequentAndTop-kElementsInDataStreams.pdf) algorithm. For example, use a CountMinSketch to track frequencies, retaining only the k largest in-memory and replacing as higher frequencies are detected.

Comment: How about a radix tree implementation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of a little bit of C++ and JNI bindings, you'd have more choices for optimized solutions. I'd suggest to try marisa-trie:

https://github.com/s-yata/marisa-trie/tree/master

I've tried several other libraries a while ago (unfortunately I don't remember the others right now) and for **my data set** marisa-trie had a very good balance between performance and memory usage compared to other C++ trie libraries.

You could also benefit from the memory mapped IO interface, for when your data grows larger (by sacrificing some performance, of course).